# Cannot update using findOrFail method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am a newbie in Laravel. So I am trying to update my form but it kept returning fail because I used the `findOrFail` method on the Controller.

But when I tried to dump the `Id`, the `Id` does exists.

Only when I call it using the method, it returns `null`.

**Route for update**

```php
Route::post('/alumni/updateProfile','AlumniController@update');
```

**Update method**

```php
public function update(Request $request, User $user, Profile $profile)
{
    $user->roles()->sync($request->roles);
    $profile = Profile::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);

    $profile->name = $request->name;
    $profile->matric_no = $request->matric_no;
    $profile->contact_no = $request->contact_no;
    $profile->address = $request->address;
    $profile->batch_year = $request->batch_year;
    $profile->graduation_year = $request->graduation_year;
    $profile->date_of_birth = $request->date_of_birth;
    $profile->area_of_interest = $request->area_of_interest;
    $profile->start_date = $request->start_date;
    $profile->company_name = $request->company_name;
    $profile->job_title = $request->job_title;
    $profile->social_network = $request->social_network;
    $profile->save();

    return view('/home', compact('profile'));
}
```

**Profile model**

```php
class Profile extends Model
{
    // protected $guarded = [];
    protected $fillable = ['alumni_id'];
    protected $table = 'profiles';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

**User model**

```php
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

    public function profiles()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Profile');
    }

    public function hasAnyRoles($roles)
    {
        if($this->roles()->whereIn('name', $roles)->first()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Glad if any of you noticed anything, thank you.

Comment: where is `user` and `profile`, and why don't u use `put`?

Comment: Why would you use findOrFail when you can just use the relationship? `Auth::user()->profiles`. Probably your profile and user have different ids, can you check?

Comment: @TsaiKoga U mean instead, of using findOrFail, i shoud use put function?

Comment: You're passing an user's id to the `Profile::findOrFail()` method. Isn't `Profile::where('alumni_id', Auth::user()->id)->firstOrFail()` what you really want?

Comment: @IGP Yes, it worked! A little bit confused by my own work. Thank you very much!

Comment: no, I mean the route. Following the RESTFUL rule, you need to use `PUT` method for `update` .  And check the [route-model-binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-model-binding).

Answer (score 0):

You can **write findOrFail() in try catch blog** and **get the exception in catch blog to understand the error**.

**OR**

you can **write below code instead of findOrFail()**.

```
$profile = Profile::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id);

if( $profile->count() ){

    # Assignment of values to database columns fields and then save.
    $profile->save();

} else {

    # Print No Record Found.

}
```